# SQLite: what is the path of my created-database?

Tags: sqlite

I have downloaded the "Precompiled Binaries for windows" for the "SQLite" from [here](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). I opened the command-line-shell and followed [this](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), creating one table named "tbl1".

now I am looking at my desk trying to find the database file which contains tbl1, but I can't find it anywhere.

my question is: after creating a database in the SQLite, where the database file is stored ? i.e.: what is the path of my created-database ?

I am using windows7 and have basic knowledge about SQL and database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default (if no additional path is specified), the database is created in the [*current working directory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

That is, `sqlite.exe ex1` creates the "ex1" database in the current directory. (Use [`cd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490875.aspx) from the same command shell to see what what the current working directory is.)

On the other hand, `sqlite.exe C:\databases\ex1` would create the "ex1" database in the "C:\databases" directory.

To create the database on the desktop for the current user, something `sqlite.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ex1"` should work. (This uses an environment variable called USERPROFILE which is expanded and used as part of the path.)

The same principle holds for any SQLite connection - the path to the database file is first resolved; either relative (as in the first case) or absolute (as in the second and third).

Answer (score 1):

It creates the DB file in the given file path else by default it will create the file in your `current working directory`. If you can't find it then just search for the `.db` file inside your current project directory.